# Terminal Background Customization?

Tags: terminal, gnome, kali-linux

Some time back, there was an option to change Terminal background in Kali Linux to an image right? Is there still a way to do it, even after it is removed during the code cleanup? 
[Maybe gconf?]

Comment: I point you to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/797418/how-to-set-a-image-as-background-of-the-gnome-terminal

Answer (score 1):

The option is not there  in `gnome-terminal` but it can be done in `konsole` (ver 17.08.03)

```
> settings
> Edit  Current Profile
> Appearance
> Edit
> Background Image (choose image and transparency)
```

Small images are tiled, larger ones are cropped to the viewport.